# Windows Identity Foundation - Local STS on Windows Azure

Tags: windows, federated-identity

I am trying to use Federated authentication on Azure. I found a example of having a local sts outside azure which is used for authentication from a web role hosted in azure. This works perfectly.

My issue is, i dont want to have an application outside azure. Instead, I want to host the local sts website also in azure. So in effect I will have two web roles (1. my actual website, 2. the sts).

I tried the above approach my creating a new webrole and moving the files from my original sts project. But i am getting compilation errors even if I reference the required dlls. I have also set "copy local" to true.

It will be very helpful if somebody can guide me..

Thanks

Comment: I solved it..The initial local sts was a website and the web role is a web application. Designer files were not available for the pages when I copied from it. So I removed and added all the pages to do this.
Thanks

Comment: I'll tell you a little story.  My boss and I attended an MS presentation about Windows Azure.  The presentation was hosted at a big movie theatre and we about half-filled the auditorium.  One of the presenters asked "How many of you are familiar with the difference betweeen a web site and a web application."  Only the two of us raised our hands.

You have job security :-)